# When is the init() function run?

Tags: go, init

I've tried to find a precise explanation of what the `init()` function does in Go. I read what [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init) says but I was unsure if I understood fully what it said. The exact sentence I am unsure is the following:

> And finally means finally: init is called after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers, and those are evaluated only after all the imported packages have been initialized.

What does `all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers` mean? Does it mean if you declare "global" variables in a package and its files, init() will not run until all of it is evaluated and then it will run all the init function and then main() when ./main_file_name is ran?

I also read Mark Summerfield's go book the following:

> If a package has one or more init() functions they are automatically executed before the main package's main() function is called.

In my understanding, `init()` is only relevant when you intend to run main() right? Anyone understands more precisely `init()` feel free to correct me

Comment: With Go 1.16 (Q1 2021): `GODEBUG=inittrace=1 go run` (or `go test`). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354109/6309).

Answer (score 630, accepted):

Yes assuming you have [this](http://play.golang.org/p/dvHymTy73F):

```
var WhatIsThe = AnswerToLife()

func AnswerToLife() int { // 1
    return 42
}

func init() { // 2
    WhatIsThe = 0
}

func main() { // 3
    if WhatIsThe == 0 {
        fmt.Println("It's all a lie.")
    }
}
```

`AnswerToLife()` is guaranteed to run before `init()` is called, and `init()` is guaranteed to run before `main()` is called.

Keep in mind that `init()` is always called, regardless if there's main or not, so if you import a package that has an `init` function, it will be executed.

Additionally, you can have multiple `init()` functions per package; they will be executed in the order they show up in the file (after all variables are initialized of course). If they span multiple files, they will be executed in lexical file name order (as pointed out by [@benc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039413/benc)):

> It seems that `init()` functions are executed in lexical file name order. The Go spec says "build systems are encouraged to present multiple files belonging to the same package in lexical file name order to a compiler". It seems that `go build` works this way.

---

A lot of the internal Go packages use `init()` to initialize tables and such, for example https://github.com/golang/go/blob/883bc6/src/compress/bzip2/bzip2.go#L480

Comment: `init()` is a per package thing, I think... Thus, does it mean that if different files have their own `inits`, all the inints are always ran right before the main() is ran? Can you also clarify for me one thing, why would you have an init() without a main and how does that work? Does it mean init() is the last thing ran before the package is imported? Otherwise, if its not imported and there is no main, the program will never execute...right? (unless its a test file I guess...)

Comment: There are a lot of reasons to run init without the package having `main`, for example if you need to initialize several variables or to load some files or do one-time-calculations. now if your entire program is one package that's not really needed, however if it's multiple packages, some of them could need to do some initialization specific to it.

Comment: @Pinocchio There will always be one (and only one) main() when you execute a go program. And init() functions are run before that one main(). However not all packages need a main(). If e.g. you're creating a reusable package with utility functions for connecting to a database, that package shouldn't have a main(). But it could have an init(). When you use that database package in a program, the program will have a main() though.

Comment: A good illustration of `init` is with a pluggable architecture, like with [Cobra commander](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#manually-create-rootcmd).  Notice how `init` is referenced in the examples

Comment: But what happens when multiple _init()_ functions are declared in different files ? What is the execution order ?

Comment: @BenC I *don't* think multiple init funcs in the same package's execution order is defined, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @OneOfOne after a few tests, it seems that *init()* functions are executed in lexical file name order. The [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) says "build systems are encouraged to present multiple files belonging to the same package in lexical file name order to a compiler". It seems that *go build* works this way.

Comment: @BenC thanks for the update, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 479):

See this picture. :)

`import --> const --> var --> init()`

[image]

1. If a package imports other packages, the imported packages are initialized first.
2. Current package's constant initialized then.
3. Current package's variables are initialized then.
4. Finally, `init()` function of current package is called.

> A package can have multiple init functions (either in a single file or distributed across multiple files) and they are called in the order in which they are presented to the compiler.

> A package will be initialised only once even if it is imported from multiple packages.

Comment: I'm not so sure that we can say constants are initialized then. They are expected to be known at compile time, right?

Comment: @KoredeLawrenceOluwafemi View the image link you will find that it's from a [book](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/) written by an Chinese Go preacher https://github.com/astaxie

Comment: and they are called in the order in which they are presented to the compiler:
In most cases they called in order of filenames, A.go, a.go, d.go, ....

Comment: thanks for the diagram, i think this answer is clearer than the accepted answer.

Comment: what can I do to first call init in main package ?

Comment: What about import statements in a different file, but in the same package as `main`?

Comment: Are those init func(s) that come from different packages invoked in the order of topology sorting with the packages' depencies?

Answer (score 29):

Something to add to this (which I would've added as a comment but the time of writing this post I'd not yet enough reputation)

Having multiple inits in the same package I've not yet found any guaranteed way to know what order in which they will be run. For example I have:

```
package config
    - config.go
    - router.go
```

Both `config.go` and `router.go` contain `init()` functions, but when running `router.go`'s function ran first (which caused my app to panic).

If you're in a situation where you have multiple files, each with its own `init()` function be very aware that you aren't guaranteed to get one before the other. It is better to use a variable assignment as [OneToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone) shows in his example. Best part is: This variable declaration will happen before ALL `init()` functions in the package.

### For example

config.go:

```
var ConfigSuccess = configureApplication()

func init() {
    doSomething()
}

func configureApplication() bool {
    l4g.Info("Configuring application...")
    if valid := loadCommandLineFlags(); !valid {
        l4g.Critical("Failed to load Command Line Flags")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

router.go:

```
func init() {
    var (
        rwd string
        tmp string
        ok  bool
    )
    if metapath, ok := Config["fs"]["metapath"].(string); ok {
        var err error
        Conn, err = services.NewConnection(metapath + "/metadata.db")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

regardless of whether `var ConfigSuccess = configureApplication()` exists in `router.go` or `config.go`, it will be run before EITHER `init()` is run.

Comment: Just my two cents: You could separate  "simple init" from complex (panic-raising) initialization. If your're panicking at init(), you're giving no chance to the main program. Maybe a `func initialize|loadConfig|connect` separated from `func init`, leaving func init() for basic stuff (without panic). This separation also removes the need of the hack to ensure init order. Hope to be helpful.

Comment: That's a good point. By panicking in init I've created an unrecoverable panic, which means I even lose logging from my log4go module. Not great. I almost wonder if to avoid the confusion of when init statements are run the best way isn't to have a separate file devoted to running init for the package. Almost like a header file.

Comment: Quote from the Language Specification: A package with no imports is initialized by assigning initial values to all its package-level variables followed by calling all init functions in the order they appear in the source, possibly in multiple files, as presented to the compiler. To ensure reproducible initialization behavior, build systems are encouraged to present multiple files belonging to the same package in lexical file name order to a compiler.

Comment: The unfortunate thing I encountered in my application was that it didn't execute the init functions in lexical order. It may have been a compiler bug that has since been fixed. I didn't bother to check if there were any issues related to this.

Comment: Important comment from updogliu above. This does not seem to hold true when imports are involved. Running into a case here where I have a test that relies on multiple imported packages. And the trick of using the package-level variables does not help me prevent init() methods on dependent packages being run before my variable assigned function.

Comment: The ordering of the `init()` calls within a single package is dictated by how they are fed into the compiler; the `go` tool orders files alphabetically. From then on, within a single file they are initialized in syntactic order.

_edited for word choice_

Answer (score 17):

Here is another example - https://play.golang.org/p/9P-LmSkUMKY

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func callOut() int {
    fmt.Println("Outside is beinge executed")
    return 1
}

var test = callOut()

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Init3 is being executed")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Init is being executed")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Init2 is being executed")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Do your thing !")
}
```

Output of the above program

```
$ go run init/init.go
Outside is being executed
Init3 is being executed
Init is being executed
Init2 is being executed
Do your thing !
```

Answer (score 13):

> When is the `init()` function run?

With Go 1.16 (Q1 2021), you will see precisely when it runs, and for how long.

See [commit 7c58ef7](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7c58ef732efd9bf0d0882bb95371ce1909924a75) from [CL (Change List) 254659](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/254659), fixing [issue 41378](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41378) .

> ### Runtime: implement `GODEBUG=inittrace=1` support
>
> Setting `inittrace=1` causes the runtime to emit a single line to standard error for
> each package with init work, summarizing the execution time and memory allocation.
>
> The emitted debug information for `init` functions can be used to find bottlenecks
> or regressions in Go startup performance.
>
> Packages with no `init` function work (user defined or compiler generated) are omitted.
>
> Tracing plugin inits is not supported as they can execute concurrently. This would
> make the implementation of tracing more complex while adding support for a very rare
> use case. Plugin inits can be traced separately by testing a main package importing
> the plugins package imports explicitly.
>
> ```sh
> $ GODEBUG=inittrace=1 go test
> init internal/bytealg @0.008 ms, 0 ms clock, 0 bytes, 0 allocs
> init runtime @0.059 ms, 0.026 ms clock, 0 bytes, 0 allocs
> init math @0.19 ms, 0.001 ms clock, 0 bytes, 0 allocs
> init errors @0.22 ms, 0.004 ms clock, 0 bytes, 0 allocs
> init strconv @0.24 ms, 0.002 ms clock, 32 bytes, 2 allocs
> init sync @0.28 ms, 0.003 ms clock, 16 bytes, 1 allocs
> init unicode @0.44 ms, 0.11 ms clock, 23328 bytes, 24 allocs
> ...
> ```
>
> Inspired by stapelberg@google.com who instrumented `doInit`
> in a prototype to measure `init` times with GDB.

Answer (score 5):

A few more tips:

> - There can only be 1 main() function, but there can be many init() functions.
> - You do not need to explicitly call init() or main(), they are called automatically.
> - init() and main() do not accept any parameters and also don't return anything.
> - init() runs before main().
> - If you have many init(), they run in the order they are declared.

Answer (score 4):

Take for example a framework or a library you're designing for other users, these users eventually will have a `main function` in their code in order to execute their app. If the user directly imports a sub-package of your library's project then the `init` of that sub-package will be called(**once**) first of all. The same for the root package of the library, etc...

There are many times when **you may want a code block to be executed** without the existence of a `main func`, directly or not.

If you, as the developer of the imaginary library, import your library's sub-package that has an `init` function, it will be called first and **once**, you don't have a `main func` but you need to make sure that some variables, or a table, will be initialized before the calls of other functions.

A good thing to remember and not to worry about, is that: 
**the `init` always execute once per application.**

`init` execution happens:

1. right before the `init` function of the "caller" package,
2. before the, optionally, `main func`,
3. but after the package-level variables, `var = [...] or cost = [...]`,

**When you import a package it will run all of its init functions, by order**.

I'll will give a very good example of an init function. It will add mime types to a standard go's library named `mime` and a package-level function will use the `mime` standard package directly to get the custom mime types that are already be initialized at its `init` function:

```
package mime

import (
    "mime"
    "path/filepath"
)

var types = map[string]string{
    ".3dm":       "x-world/x-3dmf",
    ".3dmf":      "x-world/x-3dmf",
    ".7z":        "application/x-7z-compressed",
    ".a":         "application/octet-stream",
    ".aab":       "application/x-authorware-bin",
    ".aam":       "application/x-authorware-map",
    ".aas":       "application/x-authorware-seg",
    ".abc":       "text/vndabc",
    ".ace":       "application/x-ace-compressed",
    ".acgi":      "text/html",
    ".afl":       "video/animaflex",
    ".ai":        "application/postscript",
    ".aif":       "audio/aiff",
    ".aifc":      "audio/aiff",
    ".aiff":      "audio/aiff",
    ".aim":       "application/x-aim",
    ".aip":       "text/x-audiosoft-intra",
    ".alz":       "application/x-alz-compressed",
    ".ani":       "application/x-navi-animation",
    ".aos":       "application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software",
    ".aps":       "application/mime",
    ".apk":       "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
    ".arc":       "application/x-arc-compressed",
    ".arj":       "application/arj",
    ".art":       "image/x-jg",
    ".asf":       "video/x-ms-asf",
    ".asm":       "text/x-asm",
    ".asp":       "text/asp",
    ".asx":       "application/x-mplayer2",
    ".au":        "audio/basic",
    ".avi":       "video/x-msvideo",
    ".avs":       "video/avs-video",
    ".bcpio":     "application/x-bcpio",
    ".bin":       "application/mac-binary",
    ".bmp":       "image/bmp",
    ".boo":       "application/book",
    ".book":      "application/book",
    ".boz":       "application/x-bzip2",
    ".bsh":       "application/x-bsh",
    ".bz2":       "application/x-bzip2",
    ".bz":        "application/x-bzip",
    ".c++":       "text/plain",
    ".c":         "text/x-c",
    ".cab":       "application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed",
    ".cat":       "application/vndms-pkiseccat",
    ".cc":        "text/x-c",
    ".ccad":      "application/clariscad",
    ".cco":       "application/x-cocoa",
    ".cdf":       "application/cdf",
    ".cer":       "application/pkix-cert",
    ".cha":       "application/x-chat",
    ".chat":      "application/x-chat",
    ".chrt":      "application/vnd.kde.kchart",
    ".class":     "application/java",
    ".com":       "text/plain",
    ".conf":      "text/plain",
    ".cpio":      "application/x-cpio",
    ".cpp":       "text/x-c",
    ".cpt":       "application/mac-compactpro",
    ".crl":       "application/pkcs-crl",
    ".crt":       "application/pkix-cert",
    ".crx":       "application/x-chrome-extension",
    ".csh":       "text/x-scriptcsh",
    ".css":       "text/css",
    ".csv":       "text/csv",
    ".cxx":       "text/plain",
    ".dar":       "application/x-dar",
    ".dcr":       "application/x-director",
    ".deb":       "application/x-debian-package",
    ".deepv":     "application/x-deepv",
    ".def":       "text/plain",
    ".der":       "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
    ".dif":       "video/x-dv",
    ".dir":       "application/x-director",
    ".divx":      "video/divx",
    ".dl":        "video/dl",
    ".dmg":       "application/x-apple-diskimage",
    ".doc":       "application/msword",
    ".dot":       "application/msword",
    ".dp":        "application/commonground",
    ".drw":       "application/drafting",
    ".dump":      "application/octet-stream",
    ".dv":        "video/x-dv",
    ".dvi":       "application/x-dvi",
    ".dwf":       "drawing/x-dwf=(old)",
    ".dwg":       "application/acad",
    ".dxf":       "application/dxf",
    ".dxr":       "application/x-director",
    ".el":        "text/x-scriptelisp",
    ".elc":       "application/x-bytecodeelisp=(compiled=elisp)",
    ".eml":       "message/rfc822",
    ".env":       "application/x-envoy",
    ".eps":       "application/postscript",
    ".es":        "application/x-esrehber",
    ".etx":       "text/x-setext",
    ".evy":       "application/envoy",
    ".exe":       "application/octet-stream",
    ".f77":       "text/x-fortran",
    ".f90":       "text/x-fortran",
    ".f":         "text/x-fortran",
    ".fdf":       "application/vndfdf",
    ".fif":       "application/fractals",
    ".fli":       "video/fli",
    ".flo":       "image/florian",
    ".flv":       "video/x-flv",
    ".flx":       "text/vndfmiflexstor",
    ".fmf":       "video/x-atomic3d-feature",
    ".for":       "text/x-fortran",
    ".fpx":       "image/vndfpx",
    ".frl":       "application/freeloader",
    ".funk":      "audio/make",
    ".g3":        "image/g3fax",
    ".g":         "text/plain",
    ".gif":       "image/gif",
    ".gl":        "video/gl",
    ".gsd":       "audio/x-gsm",
    ".gsm":       "audio/x-gsm",
    ".gsp":       "application/x-gsp",
    ".gss":       "application/x-gss",
    ".gtar":      "application/x-gtar",
    ".gz":        "application/x-compressed",
    ".gzip":      "application/x-gzip",
    ".h":         "text/x-h",
    ".hdf":       "application/x-hdf",
    ".help":      "application/x-helpfile",
    ".hgl":       "application/vndhp-hpgl",
    ".hh":        "text/x-h",
    ".hlb":       "text/x-script",
    ".hlp":       "application/hlp",
    ".hpg":       "application/vndhp-hpgl",
    ".hpgl":      "application/vndhp-hpgl",
    ".hqx":       "application/binhex",
    ".hta":       "application/hta",
    ".htc":       "text/x-component",
    ".htm":       "text/html",
    ".html":      "text/html",
    ".htmls":     "text/html",
    ".htt":       "text/webviewhtml",
    ".htx":       "text/html",
    ".ice":       "x-conference/x-cooltalk",
    ".ico":       "image/x-icon",
    ".ics":       "text/calendar",
    ".icz":       "text/calendar",
    ".idc":       "text/plain",
    ".ief":       "image/ief",
    ".iefs":      "image/ief",
    ".iges":      "application/iges",
    ".igs":       "application/iges",
    ".ima":       "application/x-ima",
    ".imap":      "application/x-httpd-imap",
    ".inf":       "application/inf",
    ".ins":       "application/x-internett-signup",
    ".ip":        "application/x-ip2",
    ".isu":       "video/x-isvideo",
    ".it":        "audio/it",
    ".iv":        "application/x-inventor",
    ".ivr":       "i-world/i-vrml",
    ".ivy":       "application/x-livescreen",
    ".jam":       "audio/x-jam",
    ".jav":       "text/x-java-source",
    ".java":      "text/x-java-source",
    ".jcm":       "application/x-java-commerce",
    ".jfif-tbnl": "image/jpeg",
    ".jfif":      "image/jpeg",
    ".jnlp":      "application/x-java-jnlp-file",
    ".jpe":       "image/jpeg",
    ".jpeg":      "image/jpeg",
    ".jpg":       "image/jpeg",
    ".jps":       "image/x-jps",
    ".js":        "application/javascript",
    ".json":      "application/json",
    ".jut":       "image/jutvision",
    ".kar":       "audio/midi",
    ".karbon":    "application/vnd.kde.karbon",
    ".kfo":       "application/vnd.kde.kformula",
    ".flw":       "application/vnd.kde.kivio",
    ".kml":       "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
    ".kmz":       "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",
    ".kon":       "application/vnd.kde.kontour",
    ".kpr":       "application/vnd.kde.kpresenter",
    ".kpt":       "application/vnd.kde.kpresenter",
    ".ksp":       "application/vnd.kde.kspread",
    ".kwd":       "application/vnd.kde.kword",
    ".kwt":       "application/vnd.kde.kword",
    ".ksh":       "text/x-scriptksh",
    ".la":        "audio/nspaudio",
    ".lam":       "audio/x-liveaudio",
    ".latex":     "application/x-latex",
    ".lha":       "application/lha",
    ".lhx":       "application/octet-stream",
    ".list":      "text/plain",
    ".lma":       "audio/nspaudio",
    ".log":       "text/plain",
    ".lsp":       "text/x-scriptlisp",
    ".lst":       "text/plain",
    ".lsx":       "text/x-la-asf",
    ".ltx":       "application/x-latex",
    ".lzh":       "application/octet-stream",
    ".lzx":       "application/lzx",
    ".m1v":       "video/mpeg",
    ".m2a":       "audio/mpeg",
    ".m2v":       "video/mpeg",
    ".m3u":       "audio/x-mpegurl",
    ".m":         "text/x-m",
    ".man":       "application/x-troff-man",
    ".manifest":  "text/cache-manifest",
    ".map":       "application/x-navimap",
    ".mar":       "text/plain",
    ".mbd":       "application/mbedlet",
    ".mc$":       "application/x-magic-cap-package-10",
    ".mcd":       "application/mcad",
    ".mcf":       "text/mcf",
    ".mcp":       "application/netmc",
    ".me":        "application/x-troff-me",
    ".mht":       "message/rfc822",
    ".mhtml":     "message/rfc822",
    ".mid":       "application/x-midi",
    ".midi":      "application/x-midi",
    ".mif":       "application/x-frame",
    ".mime":      "message/rfc822",
    ".mjf":       "audio/x-vndaudioexplosionmjuicemediafile",
    ".mjpg":      "video/x-motion-jpeg",
    ".mm":        "application/base64",
    ".mme":       "application/base64",
    ".mod":       "audio/mod",
    ".moov":      "video/quicktime",
    ".mov":       "video/quicktime",
    ".movie":     "video/x-sgi-movie",
    ".mp2":       "audio/mpeg",
    ".mp3":       "audio/mpeg3",
    ".mp4":       "video/mp4",
    ".mpa":       "audio/mpeg",
    ".mpc":       "application/x-project",
    ".mpe":       "video/mpeg",
    ".mpeg":      "video/mpeg",
    ".mpg":       "video/mpeg",
    ".mpga":      "audio/mpeg",
    ".mpp":       "application/vndms-project",
    ".mpt":       "application/x-project",
    ".mpv":       "application/x-project",
    ".mpx":       "application/x-project",
    ".mrc":       "application/marc",
    ".ms":        "application/x-troff-ms",
    ".mv":        "video/x-sgi-movie",
    ".my":        "audio/make",
    ".mzz":       "application/x-vndaudioexplosionmzz",
    ".nap":       "image/naplps",
    ".naplps":    "image/naplps",
    ".nc":        "application/x-netcdf",
    ".ncm":       "application/vndnokiaconfiguration-message",
    ".nif":       "image/x-niff",
    ".niff":      "image/x-niff",
    ".nix":       "application/x-mix-transfer",
    ".nsc":       "application/x-conference",
    ".nvd":       "application/x-navidoc",
    ".o":         "application/octet-stream",
    ".oda":       "application/oda",
    ".odb":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database",
    ".odc":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
    ".odf":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
    ".odg":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
    ".odi":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
    ".odm":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
    ".odp":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
    ".ods":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
    ".odt":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
    ".oga":       "audio/ogg",
    ".ogg":       "audio/ogg",
    ".ogv":       "video/ogg",
    ".omc":       "application/x-omc",
    ".omcd":      "application/x-omcdatamaker",
    ".omcr":      "application/x-omcregerator",
    ".otc":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",
    ".otf":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",
    ".otg":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
    ".oth":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",
    ".oti":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",
    ".otm":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
    ".otp":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
    ".ots":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
    ".ott":       "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
    ".p10":       "application/pkcs10",
    ".p12":       "application/pkcs-12",
    ".p7a":       "application/x-pkcs7-signature",
    ".p7c":       "application/pkcs7-mime",
    ".p7m":       "application/pkcs7-mime",
    ".p7r":       "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
    ".p7s":       "application/pkcs7-signature",
    ".p":         "text/x-pascal",
    ".part":      "application/pro_eng",
    ".pas":       "text/pascal",
    ".pbm":       "image/x-portable-bitmap",
    ".pcl":       "application/vndhp-pcl",
    ".pct":       "image/x-pict",
    ".pcx":       "image/x-pcx",
    ".pdb":       "chemical/x-pdb",
    ".pdf":       "application/pdf",
    ".pfunk":     "audio/make",
    ".pgm":       "image/x-portable-graymap",
    ".pic":       "image/pict",
    ".pict":      "image/pict",
    ".pkg":       "application/x-newton-compatible-pkg",
    ".pko":       "application/vndms-pkipko",
    ".pl":        "text/x-scriptperl",
    ".plx":       "application/x-pixclscript",
    ".pm4":       "application/x-pagemaker",
    ".pm5":       "application/x-pagemaker",
    ".pm":        "text/x-scriptperl-module",
    ".png":       "image/png",
    ".pnm":       "application/x-portable-anymap",
    ".pot":       "application/mspowerpoint",
    ".pov":       "model/x-pov",
    ".ppa":       "application/vndms-powerpoint",
    ".ppm":       "image/x-portable-pixmap",
    ".pps":       "application/mspowerpoint",
    ".ppt":       "application/mspowerpoint",
    ".ppz":       "application/mspowerpoint",
    ".pre":       "application/x-freelance",
    ".prt":       "application/pro_eng",
    ".ps":        "application/postscript",
    ".psd":       "application/octet-stream",
    ".pvu":       "paleovu/x-pv",
    ".pwz":       "application/vndms-powerpoint",
    ".py":        "text/x-scriptphyton",
    ".pyc":       "application/x-bytecodepython",
    ".qcp":       "audio/vndqcelp",
    ".qd3":       "x-world/x-3dmf",
    ".qd3d":      "x-world/x-3dmf",
    ".qif":       "image/x-quicktime",
    ".qt":        "video/quicktime",
    ".qtc":       "video/x-qtc",
    ".qti":       "image/x-quicktime",
    ".qtif":      "image/x-quicktime",
    ".ra":        "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    ".ram":       "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    ".rar":       "application/x-rar-compressed",
    ".ras":       "application/x-cmu-raster",
    ".rast":      "image/cmu-raster",
    ".rexx":      "text/x-scriptrexx",
    ".rf":        "image/vndrn-realflash",
    ".rgb":       "image/x-rgb",
    ".rm":        "application/vndrn-realmedia",
    ".rmi":       "audio/mid",
    ".rmm":       "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    ".rmp":       "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    ".rng":       "application/ringing-tones",
    ".rnx":       "application/vndrn-realplayer",
    ".roff":      "application/x-troff",
    ".rp":        "image/vndrn-realpix",
    ".rpm":       "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
    ".rt":        "text/vndrn-realtext",
    ".rtf":       "text/richtext",
    ".rtx":       "text/richtext",
    ".rv":        "video/vndrn-realvideo",
    ".s":         "text/x-asm",
    ".s3m":       "audio/s3m",
    ".s7z":       "application/x-7z-compressed",
    ".saveme":    "application/octet-stream",
    ".sbk":       "application/x-tbook",
    ".scm":       "text/x-scriptscheme",
    ".sdml":      "text/plain",
    ".sdp":       "application/sdp",
    ".sdr":       "application/sounder",
    ".sea":       "application/sea",
    ".set":       "application/set",
    ".sgm":       "text/x-sgml",
    ".sgml":      "text/x-sgml",
    ".sh":        "text/x-scriptsh",
    ".shar":      "application/x-bsh",
    ".shtml":     "text/x-server-parsed-html",
    ".sid":       "audio/x-psid",
    ".skd":       "application/x-koan",
    ".skm":       "application/x-koan",
    ".skp":       "application/x-koan",
    ".skt":       "application/x-koan",
    ".sit":       "application/x-stuffit",
    ".sitx":      "application/x-stuffitx",
    ".sl":        "application/x-seelogo",
    ".smi":       "application/smil",
    ".smil":      "application/smil",
    ".snd":       "audio/basic",
    ".sol":       "application/solids",
    ".spc":       "text/x-speech",
    ".spl":       "application/futuresplash",
    ".spr":       "application/x-sprite",
    ".sprite":    "application/x-sprite",
    ".spx":       "audio/ogg",
    ".src":       "application/x-wais-source",
    ".ssi":       "text/x-server-parsed-html",
    ".ssm":       "application/streamingmedia",
    ".sst":       "application/vndms-pkicertstore",
    ".step":      "application/step",
    ".stl":       "application/sla",
    ".stp":       "application/step",
    ".sv4cpio":   "application/x-sv4cpio",
    ".sv4crc":    "application/x-sv4crc",
    ".svf":       "image/vnddwg",
    ".svg":       "image/svg+xml",
    ".svr":       "application/x-world",
    ".swf":       "application/x-shockwave-flash",
    ".t":         "application/x-troff",
    ".talk":      "text/x-speech",
    ".tar":       "application/x-tar",
    ".tbk":       "application/toolbook",
    ".tcl":       "text/x-scripttcl",
    ".tcsh":      "text/x-scripttcsh",
    ".tex":       "application/x-tex",
    ".texi":      "application/x-texinfo",
    ".texinfo":   "application/x-texinfo",
    ".text":      "text/plain",
    ".tgz":       "application/gnutar",
    ".tif":       "image/tiff",
    ".tiff":      "image/tiff",
    ".tr":        "application/x-troff",
    ".tsi":       "audio/tsp-audio",
    ".tsp":       "application/dsptype",
    ".tsv":       "text/tab-separated-values",
    ".turbot":    "image/florian",
    ".txt":       "text/plain",
    ".uil":       "text/x-uil",
    ".uni":       "text/uri-list",
    ".unis":      "text/uri-list",
    ".unv":       "application/i-deas",
    ".uri":       "text/uri-list",
    ".uris":      "text/uri-list",
    ".ustar":     "application/x-ustar",
    ".uu":        "text/x-uuencode",
    ".uue":       "text/x-uuencode",
    ".vcd":       "application/x-cdlink",
    ".vcf":       "text/x-vcard",
    ".vcard":     "text/x-vcard",
    ".vcs":       "text/x-vcalendar",
    ".vda":       "application/vda",
    ".vdo":       "video/vdo",
    ".vew":       "application/groupwise",
    ".viv":       "video/vivo",
    ".vivo":      "video/vivo",
    ".vmd":       "application/vocaltec-media-desc",
    ".vmf":       "application/vocaltec-media-file",
    ".voc":       "audio/voc",
    ".vos":       "video/vosaic",
    ".vox":       "audio/voxware",
    ".vqe":       "audio/x-twinvq-plugin",
    ".vqf":       "audio/x-twinvq",
    ".vql":       "audio/x-twinvq-plugin",
    ".vrml":      "application/x-vrml",
    ".vrt":       "x-world/x-vrt",
    ".vsd":       "application/x-visio",
    ".vst":       "application/x-visio",
    ".vsw":       "application/x-visio",
    ".w60":       "application/wordperfect60",
    ".w61":       "application/wordperfect61",
    ".w6w":       "application/msword",
    ".wav":       "audio/wav",
    ".wb1":       "application/x-qpro",
    ".wbmp":      "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
    ".web":       "application/vndxara",
    ".wiz":       "application/msword",
    ".wk1":       "application/x-123",
    ".wmf":       "windows/metafile",
    ".wml":       "text/vnd.wap.wml",
    ".wmlc":      "application/vnd.wap.wmlc",
    ".wmls":      "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript",
    ".wmlsc":     "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc",
    ".word":      "application/msword",
    ".wp5":       "application/wordperfect",
    ".wp6":       "application/wordperfect",
    ".wp":        "application/wordperfect",
    ".wpd":       "application/wordperfect",
    ".wq1":       "application/x-lotus",
    ".wri":       "application/mswrite",
    ".wrl":       "application/x-world",
    ".wrz":       "model/vrml",
    ".wsc":       "text/scriplet",
    ".wsrc":      "application/x-wais-source",
    ".wtk":       "application/x-wintalk",
    ".x-png":     "image/png",
    ".xbm":       "image/x-xbitmap",
    ".xdr":       "video/x-amt-demorun",
    ".xgz":       "xgl/drawing",
    ".xif":       "image/vndxiff",
    ".xl":        "application/excel",
    ".xla":       "application/excel",
    ".xlb":       "application/excel",
    ".xlc":       "application/excel",
    ".xld":       "application/excel",
    ".xlk":       "application/excel",
    ".xll":       "application/excel",
    ".xlm":       "application/excel",
    ".xls":       "application/excel",
    ".xlt":       "application/excel",
    ".xlv":       "application/excel",
    ".xlw":       "application/excel",
    ".xm":        "audio/xm",
    ".xml":       "text/xml",
    ".xmz":       "xgl/movie",
    ".xpix":      "application/x-vndls-xpix",
    ".xpm":       "image/x-xpixmap",
    ".xsr":       "video/x-amt-showrun",
    ".xwd":       "image/x-xwd",
    ".xyz":       "chemical/x-pdb",
    ".z":         "application/x-compress",
    ".zip":       "application/zip",
    ".zoo":       "application/octet-stream",
    ".zsh":       "text/x-scriptzsh",
    ".docx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    ".docm":      "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12",
    ".dotx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",
    ".dotm":      "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12",
    ".xlsx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    ".xlsm":      "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12",
    ".xltx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template",
    ".xltm":      "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12",
    ".xlsb":      "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12",
    ".xlam":      "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12",
    ".pptx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    ".pptm":      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12",
    ".ppsx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow",
    ".ppsm":      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12",
    ".potx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template",
    ".potm":      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12",
    ".ppam":      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12",
    ".sldx":      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide",
    ".sldm":      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12",
    ".thmx":      "application/vnd.ms-officetheme",
    ".onetoc":    "application/onenote",
    ".onetoc2":   "application/onenote",
    ".onetmp":    "application/onenote",
    ".onepkg":    "application/onenote",
    ".xpi":       "application/x-xpinstall",
}

func init() {
    for ext, typ := range types {
        // skip errors
        mime.AddExtensionType(ext, typ)
    }
}

// typeByExtension returns the MIME type associated with the file extension ext.
// The extension ext should begin with a leading dot, as in ".html".
// When ext has no associated type, typeByExtension returns "".
//
// Extensions are looked up first case-sensitively, then case-insensitively.
//
// The built-in table is small but on unix it is augmented by the local
// system's mime.types file(s) if available under one or more of these
// names:
//
//   /etc/mime.types
//   /etc/apache2/mime.types
//   /etc/apache/mime.types
//
// On Windows, MIME types are extracted from the registry.
//
// Text types have the charset parameter set to "utf-8" by default.
func TypeByExtension(fullfilename string) string {
    ext := filepath.Ext(fullfilename)
    typ := mime.TypeByExtension(ext)

    // mime.TypeByExtension returns as text/plain; | charset=utf-8 the static .js (not always)
    if ext == ".js" && (typ == "text/plain" || typ == "text/plain; charset=utf-8") {

        if ext == ".js" {
            typ = "application/javascript"
        }
    }
    return typ
}
```

Hope that helped you and other users, don't hesitate to post again if you have more questions!

Answer (score 4):

mutil init function in one package execute order:

1. const and variable defined file init() function execute
2. init function execute order by the filename asc

Comment: `filename asc` now it all makes snese, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_4

> Program initialization runs in a single goroutine, but that goroutine may create other goroutines, which run concurrently.
>
> If a package p imports package q, the completion of q's init functions happens before the start of any of p's.
>
> The start of the function main.main happens after all init functions have finished.

Answer (score 0):

`init` will be called everywhere uses its package(no matter blank import or import), but only one time.

this is a package:

```
package demo

import (
    "some/logs"
)

var count int

func init() {
    logs.Debug(count)
}

// Do do
func Do() {
    logs.Debug("dd")
}
```

any package(main package or any test package) import it as blank :

```
_ "printfcoder.com/we/models/demo"
```

or import it using it func:

```
"printfcoder.com/we/models/demo"

func someFunc(){
   demo.Do()
}
```

the init will log `0` only one time.
the first package using it, its init func will run before the package's init. So:

A calls B, B calls C, all of them have init func, the C's init will be run first before B's, B's before A's.

Answer (score -1):

The init func runs first and then main. It's used for setting something first  before your program runs, for example:

Accessing a template, 
 Running the program using all cores,
 Checking the Goos and arch etc...