# Why can't you name a function in Go "init"?

Tags: go, naming, internal

So, today while I was coding I found out that creating a function with the name `init` generated an error `method init() not found`, but when I renamed it to `startup` it all worked fine.

Is the word "init" preserved for some internal operation in Go or am I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the function `init()` is special. It is automatically executed when a package is loaded. Even the package `main` may contain one or more `init()` functions that are executed before the actual program begins: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init

It is part of the package initialization, as explained in the language specification: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization

It is commonly used to initialize package variables, etc.

Comment: Note that you can name a function on a struct init and you can call it.

Answer (score 11):

You can also see the different errors you can get when using `init` in [`golang/test/init.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/test/init.go)

```
// Verify that erroneous use of init is detected.
// Does not compile.

package main

import "runtime"

func init() {
}

func main() {
    init() // ERROR "undefined.*init"
    runtime.init() // ERROR "unexported.*runtime\.init"
    var _ = init // ERROR "undefined.*init"
}
```

`init` itself is managed by [`golang/cmd/gc/init.c`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6592456feb7a9f934e82f2fde1ef2b395eaa44f8/src/cmd/gc/init.c):
Now in [`cmd/compile/internal/gc/init.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/dcb84828a6b1d7d4d9186bc6d752cc147e255162/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/init.go#L12):

```
/*
* a function named init is a special case.
* it is called by the initialization before
* main is run. to make it unique within a
* package and also uncallable, the name,
* normally "pkg.init", is altered to "pkg.init·1".
*/
```

Its use is illustrated in "[When is the `init()` function in go (golang) run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790378/6309)"

Comment: The comment about the init function is now at: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/init.go#L12

Comment: @user674669 Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.