# Viper, cannot get the value initialized outside the functions

Tags: go

I have a problem using a viper, I have assigned variable by viper method, so when I try to get value inside any function I have a null value. Does anybody have any idea why does it happen so? Any other variables initialization works fine, but not viper GetString method.

Structure:
main.go

```
    package main

    import (
        "project/Model"
        "github.com/spf13/viper"
        ...
    )

    func main() {
        //Config handling
        viper.SetConfigName("main")
        viper.AddConfigPath("/config/")
        err = viper.ReadInConfig()
        ...
    }
```

Package Model

```
    package Model

    import ("github.com/spf13/viper"
        ...
    )

    var sqlhost = viper.GetString("db.host")

    func foo() {
        log.Println(sqlhost)
    }
```

Comment: Since `viper.GetString` return `string` (not a pointer), it won't be null. Do you mean that the return value is *empty string*? First, check whether the key exists or not by `viper.IsSet`.

Comment: sorry, yes, string is empty. Key exists, because when I'm using getString  inside func it gives me a value which i need.

Comment: It means that `viper.GetString` is called before viper configuration is initialized, e.g. by `viper.ReadConfig` etc. Use [`init()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790175/when-is-the-init-function-run) function.

Comment: Probably more of a style difference, but I'd prefer the `viper.ReadConfig` etc. to be in the `main()` function, and retrieving the values inside of the functions that use it rather than as a package var initialization.

Comment: well I follow Your advice, it works now. Thank You so much for Your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that doing package variable initialization as you show will lead to the viper configuration not being complete before performing the `GetString()`, and therefore the zero (empty) string value is what is returned.  Without seeing how you initialize your viper config, I'm guessing that it's not in an `init()` function, but is in a `main()` function that hasn't run yet when the package variable is assigned.

You should probably retrieve the `viper.GetString("db.host")` inside the highest level function that needs it rather than during package initialization.

Comment: well viper initialization is in a main() function You're guessing right (and excuse me, i missed it), but variable init is in another package

Comment: Yeah, see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#initialization.  Probably the other package is initializing viper after this variable is assigned

Comment: well, i edited my question a bit, i cannot realize why the method inside the function returns right value, but the outside call gives empty. if it would be reinitialization it wouldn't give me a config value.