# How golang's init() works. I am confused

Tags: go

I have a init() function defined in "config/config.go"

config.go

```
package config

import(
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func init() {
    log.SetReportCaller(true)
}
```

I have another go file called auth.go in auth package

```
package auth

import(
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func auth(username string, pwd string) {
     //some auth code
    log.Info("Auth success")
}
```

When log.Info() is called in auth.go the log prints as below

```
2018-11-09T16:38:27+05:30 auth/auth.go:36 level=info msg="Auth success"
```

What I am confused here is that, how "log" in auth.go is aware of the settings done in `config.go`. `log.SetReportCaller()` is in `config.go` but even when `auth.go` is logged it takes settings of log.SetReportCaller() done in config.go

Since log.SetReportCaller() is not set in auth.go expected log should be as below without showing line number of caller method.

```
2018-11-09T16:38:27+05:30 level=info msg="Auth success"
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "path/to/auth" 
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
 )

func main() {
    r := server.Route()

    log.Info("Listening on 8080")

    http.Handle("/", r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

auth/router.go

```
package auth

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "net/http"
)

func Route() http.Handler {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    // UI handlers
    r.HandleFunc("/", IndexPageHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/login", LoginHandler).Methods("POST")
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
    return 
}
```

auth/login.go

```
package auth

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/to/config"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
)
func LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    username := r.FormValue("username")
    password := r.FormValue("password")

    status, userName, mail, _ := auth(username, password)
    //some code goes here

}
```

Kindly explain how this is happening

Comment: can you show the file where your `main` function is. I am suspecting that file imports `config` package.

Comment: question is updated with main.go code

Comment: We can't see the dependency tree so I'm guessing `config` is a dependency somewhere here. if that is the case, it is not mystery why the `init()` function is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the init() function run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790175/when-is-the-init-function-run)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this diagram to understand how `init()` work: [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49831018/7695859)

Initialization order are as follows,

1. If a package imports other packages, the imported packages are initialised first.
2. Package level variables are initialised then.
3. init function of current package is called next. A package can have multiple init functions (either in a single file or distributed across multiple files) and they are called in the order in which they are presented to the compiler.

You will found an example explaining this [here](https://github.com/hossainemruz/notebook/blob/master/go/basic.md#init-function).

I am suspecting in dependency tree, there is a common ancestor file that import both `config` package and `auth` package.

Here is official doc on initialization: [Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization)

**UPD:** As you have added respective codes, let's visualize what is happening here. Look at the picture bellow,

[image]

What happening:

1. Your **main** package start initialing. But it is has imported **auth** package. So to complete initialization, **auth** package must be initialized.
2. **auth** package start initializing. But it has imported **config** package. So to complete initialization, **config** package must be initialized.
3. **config** package complete initialization(`log.SetReportCaller(true)` is called).
4. **auth** package complete initialization.
5. **main** package complete initialization.
6. `main()` function starts executing...

Comment: @peterSO thank you for pointing me there. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: I have added all the dependent code. Kindly refer the edited question and throw me some light on how dependency is working here.

Comment: @AdityaCS I have updated my answer to explain what is happening.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Still my doubt is, is the "log" package imported and referenced in main.go the same as "log" imported and referenced in config.go. Both imports has different "log" reference right? How it still works?

Comment: @Adrian  has already answer this in his answer. "`SetReportCaller` sets a global variable in github.com/sirupsen/logrus" .  All imports from different packages refers to same instance until you create new one using `logrus.New()`

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're asking about actually has nothing to do with how `init()` functions work. `SetReportCaller` sets a global variable in `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`, not in your `config` or `auth` packages. So it doesn't matter where you call that function or where you call `log.Info` et al; the setting affects all calls to logrus regardless of call origin.