# Config file type usage

Tags: go, configuration

Usually I saw config file in many examples out there are in .env or .json file.

What if I decide to use .go file instead , is it uncommon, how it should be done?

I was thinking since .env file is static, if I want to put config like this

```
var currentDate = time.Now()
var currentDateFormat = currentDate.Format("2006-01-02")
var logPath = dir + "/log/" + currentDateFormat + ".log"
```

It can't be done in .env file so should I just keep the above config within function somewhere and stick with .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I decide to use .go file instead

Then it is no longer a config file (static content), but a source file, which needs to be compiled and part of your exe (runtime content).

It then could be part of an [`init()` function](https://medium.com/golangspec/init-functions-in-go-eac191b3860a) for instance.
Or part of a [`config` package source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27388866/6309), in charge of loading your config as well as initializing the variables in your question.

Comment: so is it not recommended? stick with static file?

Comment: @Ardeus Both have their role: static file for static data, source code for dynamic runtime values (like `time.Now()`... which can makes sense only at runtime)