# How to call unexported function within package?

Tags: go, goland

I'm trying to write a package to work with. Here is sample code:

```
package redis

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var conn redis.Conn

func init() {
    // code to set conn variable
}

func do(command string, args ...interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    init()
    return conn.Do(command, args)
}
```

This code does not compile and compilator says `undefined: init`. When I change `init()` to `Init()` it works, but I don't want it to be available outside of package.
Wherever I read about this problem, it says about calling unexported function from *another* package, but here I'm calling it from same one.

Also, Goland IDE marks function call as `unresolved reference` and suggests to create it. But when I do (by IDE itself), it still doesn't see it.

Comment: how is it different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790175/when-is-the-init-function-run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go, `init` is reserved for initializing work that needs to be done in a package, eg. adding some implementation to some registry.

To solve this problem, you need to use another name.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790175/when-is-the-init-function-run) to learn more about `init` if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue! So I don't have to call init(), just define it and it will work?

Comment: Yes, the init() function is called on startup, i.e. before the main()

Answer (score 5):

init() is a special function. From the language spec:

> func init() { … }
>
> Multiple such functions may be defined per package, even within a 
>    single source file. In the package block, the init identifier can 
>    be used only to declare init functions, yet the identifier itself 
>    is not declared. Thus init functions cannot be referred to from 
>    anywhere in a program.

Use `init()` for package level initializations.